# How to rotate Image using native javascript

Tags: javascript, image, rotation

I'm developing a game using HTML5 canvas element and native javascript. I have different sprites for game objects. Is it possible to rotate sprites using native javascript?

For example, I have a sprite image like this:

[image]

I use [Image](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp) for this sprite:

```
var image = new Image(...);

image.src = "...";
```

After loading I want to rotate this image and save different projections in local variables:

```
var sprite_left = rotate(image, 0),
    sprite_top = rotate(image, 90),
    sprite_right = rotate(image, 180),
    sprite_right = rotate(image, 270);
```

The rotate function should look like this:

```
function rotate(sourceImage, angle){
...
}
```

Could anybody help me to write the rotate function?

**EDIT:**

I have decided to share my code, which I used to test my sprites:

```
    var wait = function (image, completed, count) {
        if (count == null) count = 0;
        if (!image.complete && count < 1000) {
            count++;
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                wait(image, completed, count);
                console.log('waiting...');
            }, 10);
        }
        else {
            completed();
        }
    },

    rotateW = function (image) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;

        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerText = "W: ";
        p.appendChild(canvas);
        document.body.appendChild(p);

        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
        context.rotate(Math.PI);
        context.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2);
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        var newImage = new Image();
        newImage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        return newImage;
    },

    rotateE = function (image) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;

        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerText = "E: ";
        p.appendChild(canvas);
        document.body.appendChild(p);

        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        var newImage = new Image();
        newImage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        return newImage;
    },
    rotateS = function (image, frameCount) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = image.height * frameCount;
        canvas.height = image.width / frameCount;

        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerText = "S: ";
        p.appendChild(canvas);
        document.body.appendChild(p);

        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.translate(image.height / 2, image.width / (2 * frameCount));
        context.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
        var i = frameCount;
        while (i--> 0) {
            context.drawImage(image, - image.width / 2 , - ( 0.5 + i ) * image.height);
        }
        var newImage = new Image();
        newImage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        return newImage;
    },
    rotateN = function (image, frameCount) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = image.height * frameCount;
        canvas.height = image.width / frameCount;

        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerText = "N: ";
        p.appendChild(canvas);
        document.body.appendChild(p);

        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.translate(image.height / 2, image.width / (2 * frameCount));
        context.rotate( 3 * Math.PI / 2);
        var i = frameCount;
        while (i-- > 0) {
            context.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, (frameCount - i - 1.5) * image.height);
        }
        var newImage = new Image();
        newImage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        return newImage;
    };
/*
        N
        |
   W----O----E
        |
        S
*/
getSprites = function (image, frameCount) {
    var sprite = {
        N: rotateN(image, frameCount),
        S: rotateS(image, frameCount),
        W: rotateW(image, frameCount),
        E: rotateE(image, frameCount)
    };
    return [      
        sprite.W, // left
        sprite.N, // up
        sprite.E, // right
        sprite.S] // down
};

$.sprite = {
    register: function (options) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = options.src;

        wait(image, function () {
            var sprites = getSprites(image, options.frameCount);
        });
    }
};
```

The final result is:

[image]

Comment: Either use CSS or instead of `<img>`, use a `<canvas>`.

Comment: Using of CSS or <canvas> could lead to performance issues :(

Comment: How about using a `<canvas>` to pre-render the different rotations, then storing these in memory using `toBlob`, converting these blobs to _URLs_ with `window.URL.createObjectURL` and then swap urls as desired. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement for canvas options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a `<canvas>` to pre-render the different rotations
2. Store these in memory using via `toBlob`, optionally converting these blobs to URLs with `window.URL.createObjectURL`
3. Swap URLs as desired.

See [**this** MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement) for canvas options

Answer (score 3):

the following function will create a new Canvas out
of img (which might be an image or a canvas).
Give it an angle in radian, or 'N', 'S', 'W' for
the corresponding rotation.

```
function createRotatedImage(img, angle) {
     angle = (angle == 'N') ?  -Math.PI/2 :
             (angle == 'S') ?   Math.PI/2 :
             (angle == 'W') ?   Math.PI   :
              angle ;    
     var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
     newCanvas.width  = img.width  ;
     newCanvas.height = img.height ;
     var newCtx = newCanvas.getContext('2d') ;
     newCtx.save      () ;
     newCtx.translate ( img.width / 2, img.height / 2) ;
     newCtx.rotate  (angle);
     newCtx.drawImage ( img, - img.width / 2, - img.height / 2) ; 
     newCtx.restore   () ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely!  It's not as simple as rotating the image, though.  You need to rotate the context from the canvas, and draw that image on the rotated context, and then restore it.

```
context.save();
context.rotate(angle);

//DRAW IT!

context.restore();
```

Comment: I think the OP wants each part of the image to be rotated & saved before rendering it on canvas...

Answer (score 1):

How about having a function like :

```
Image.prototype.rotate = function(angle) {
    var c = document.createElement("canvas");
    c.width = this.width;
    c.height = this.height;    
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");    
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    var imgData = ctx.createImageData(this.width, this.height);
    ctx.putImageData(imgData);
    return new Image(imgData);
}

var img1 = new Image();
var img2 = img1.rotate(90);
```

Ofcourse it's just a quick sample to give you an idea.

Comment: i think you meant ctx.putImageData(this), and only after you retrieve the imageData. But in fact just returning the canvas is ok, since putImage works even faster with a canvas than with an image.

Comment: How to perform rotation without showing the img in the dom or rendering it ? I want to get the base64 of the final rotated image only